# Why did Marvel characters from the 80s often have blue hair?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men

Looking at 1980s X-men comic books, I notice so many characters had blue hair, for example, Wolverine, Beast, Mr.Sinister, and tons of no-name extras.  Probably this goes beyond the X-men, but that’s the comic I have in front of me to verify this phenomenon.  I suspect it had something to do with the available color pallet. Typically the hair is actually blue and black.  Does anyone have a definitive answer why so many characters had blue hair?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could improve this question by adding a few images that show what you're looking at, and by identifying specific issues that this question applies to.

Comment: In Marvel comics, this always seemed less noticeable to me as an artistic convention than the flattened shapes of the fingertips.

Answer (score 24):

It's a long-time comics convention, not just used by Marvel. The hair is actually black but to avoid a solid black patch on the page the highlights are depicted in a contrasting colour, usually blue. There was a 1985 DC mini-series called *Superman: The Secret Years* in which the highlights were brown, not blue, which to my eyes at least looked odd.  [Here's the cover of the first issue:](https://files1.comics.org//img/gcd/covers_by_id/14/w400/14647.jpg?6328424258149933020)

Comment: in other words, the characters have black hair with _really glossy_ blue hair-gel on? ;)

Comment: Maybe true for Wolverine or Mr. Sinister.  Beast, however, is explicitly blue.

Comment: @ilkkachu Not necessarily even blue gel. Depending on the lighting and the composition of the gel itself, the gloss can _look_ blue even though the gel is not, though this is usually not as blatant in real life as it is in the comics.